# Labour Party support for renationalizing railways

Tags: united-kingdom, labour-party

What arguments does the Labour Party state for their support for renationalizing the railways?

Comment: Any sources to read up on regarding this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The least ambiguous source for this might be [page 90 of the Labour Party manifesto for the 2017 General Election](http://labour.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/labour-manifesto-2017.pdf)

> **Labour will invest in a modern, integrated, accessible and sustainable transport system that is reliable and a affordable.**
>
> Our transport systems illustrate
>   the abject failure of Tory policies: relentless deregulation, privatisation and fragmentation.
>
> They say we get choice and efficiency but the reality of their transport privatisations has been that services are less reliable, safety is compromised, fares have risen, ticketing has become complicated and air quality has worsened.
>
> On our railways, we pay some of the highest fares in Europe for increasingly unreliable and overcrowded services.
>   The beneficiaries of public funding siphoned off through transport privatisations have been the earnings of directors, dividends for shareholders and the coffers of overseas governments.
>
> Labour will prioritise public service over private profit. And we will start by bringing our railways back into public ownership, as franchises expire or, in other cases, with franchise reviews or break clauses. We will introduce a Public Ownership of the Railways Bill to repeal the
>   Railways Act 1993 under which the Conservatives privatised our railways.
>
> In public ownership, we will deliver real improvements for passengers by capping fares, introducing free wi-fi across the network, ensuring safe staffing levels, ending the expansion of driver only operations, and introducing legal duties to improve accessibility for people with disabilities.
>
> Across the country we will enable councils to provide first-class bus services by extending the powers to re-regulate local bus services to all areas that want them, and we will support the creation of municipal bus companies that are publicly run for passengers not profit.
>
> Under the Conservatives, bus fares have risen and services have been cut. Labour will introduce regulations to designate and protect routes of critical community value, including those that serve local schools, hospitals and isolated settlements in rural areas.
>
> A publicly owned railway system can be the backbone of our plans for integrated transport. It will be built on the platform of Network Rail, which we will retain whole, working with the devolved administrations. We will ensure new rolling stock is publicly owned and will encourage expansion of public freight services in a publicly owned railway that will leave our roads freer of traffic and our air cleaner. We will facilitate British procurements, including steel, whenever possible.